# Programmatically Access ANTLr Grammar Rule String Literals outside of a parse context

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, antlr4

I'm trying to ensure that a mapping between allowed values defined by an ANTLr grammar and a set of type URIs defined in a property file in the same project stay in sync with each other (i.e. we run into problems when the grammar gets updated but someone forgets to add the corresponding type URI into the property file for the matching token.  I would like to be able to add a unit test to the project which checks for the mismatch by programmatically accessing the contents of a grammar rule.

Consider the following contrived grammar:

```
grammar RuleTokenExtractionExample

// Parser Rules

start
    : line EOF
    ;

line
    : WS* fields WS*
    ;

fields
    : field (DELIMITER field)*
    ;

field
    : color
    | fruit
    | number
    ;

color
    : 'Red'
    | 'Orange'
    | 'Yellow'
    | 'Green'
    | 'Blue'
    | 'Indigo'
    | 'Violet'
    ;

fruit
    : 'Apple'
    | 'Apricot'
    | 'Banana'
    | 'Grapefruit'
    | 'Orange'
    | 'Pear'
    | 'Plum'
    ;

number
    : DIGIT (DIGIT*)
    ;

// Lexer Rules

DELIMITER: ',';
WS: [ \t];
DIGIT: [0-9];
```

In my code, I would like to be able to make a call into the grammar to obtain the tokens defined for a rule like "color" (e.g. something like `myLexer.getVocabulary().getRule(RULE_color).getChildTokens();` resulting in a collection object whose contents are "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", and "Violet").

Is there a way to do this in ANTLr?

I'm coding in Java, in case that matters.

---

Combining the responses from @mike-lischke and @kaby76, I ended up with something similar to the following solution.  It's probably not quite right but did what I needed.  I welcome corrections from the more wiser and experienced with ANTLr (as I'm neither of those).

```
public class RuleExtractor {
    public static Set<String> getTokensForRule(int ruleId) {
        Pattern quotedStringLiteral = Pattern.compile("'([^']+)'");
        Grammar grammar = new RuleTokenExtractionExampleGrammar(null);
        ATNState ruleState = grammar.getAtn().ruleToStartState[ruleId];

        Queue<ATNState> queue = new LinkedList();
        Stream.of(ruleState.getTransitions())
                .map(state -> state.target)
                .forEach(queue::add);

        List<String> tokens = new LinkedList<>();
        ATNState state;
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            state = queue.remove();
            Stream.of(state.getTransitions())
                    .forEach(transition -> {
                        if (transition.getSerializationType() == Transition.ATOM) {
                            Matcher matcher = SINGLE_QUOTED_STRING.matcher(getTokenDisplayName(transition
                                    .label()
                                    .get(0)));
                            tokens.add(matcher.matches() ? matcher.group(1) : matcher.group(0));
                        } else {
                            queue.add(transition.target);
                        }
                    });
        }

        return tokens;
    }
}
```

Giving the following command as the answer to my original question:

```
List<String> tokens = RuleExtractor.getTokensForRule(RuleTokenExtractionExampleGrammar.RULE_color);
System.out.println(String.join(", ", tokens));
// Produces: Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet
```

Or at least it should.  I didn't actually test the solution with the contrived grammar.

Comment: You need to access the Parser.Atn object through the runtime to get the ATNState corresponding to the "color" rule, then follow the transitions until you get to the first non-empty transition state (43). The non-empty transition from state 43 will contain a set of symbols "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", and "Violet". To see what state 43 looks like, you will need to generate DOT graphs for the grammar using the tool, and look at the file RuleTokenExtractionExample.color.dot on Webgraphviz.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info you are looking for is stored in the ATN that's generated from your grammar. There is a class [`LL1Analyzer`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/LL1Analyzer.java), which returns all tokens that are reachable within a single rule, from a given ATN state.

Pass in the start state from your `color` rule. Use your generated parser to look up the number of that rule (it's a static constant there) and use the ATN returned from `yourparser.getAtn()` to lookup that state from the rule number, via `ATN.ruleToStartState`.

There's one caveat, however, you will need a `RuleContext` to use the `LL1Analyzer` class. Because of this and other limitations, I rewrote this lookup in my [code completion core engine](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3/blob/master/src/CodeCompletionCore.ts#L228). This code is written in Typescript, but there's a [Java port](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3/tree/master/ports/java) too.

Comment: Mike, thank you for the response, I'm attempting to work with it now but would understand your explanation better if you could define "ATN" for me.  The ANTLr docs refer to it a lot but I can't find a definition.

Comment: @core See for instance [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_transition_network) for an explanantion and further links.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll need to review the Java port of your code again as I'm missing some logic.  I'm getting extra characters I wasn't expecting coming back from the Lexer (token delimiters, whitespace placeholders, that sort of thing).